# how to use uib-tabset in angular2 using ng-bootstrap?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I am working in angular2 project and would like to know is there any mean by which i can use uib-tabset in angular2?

I previously used angularjs with which I could use ng-bootstrap.

so I could use `<uib-tabset></uib-tabset>` easily.

But I am not sure about how to do this in angular2?
any inputs?

Comment: I would write a comment... if I could ... You are looking for this:
https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/tabs This is from valor-software the ng2-bootstrap.

Answer (score 7):

The equivalent of the `angular-ui/bootstrap` for Angular 2 is named `ng-bootstrap` and you can see its source code in https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap.

The tab component is part of https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap and was renamed to `ngb-tabset`. You can see it in action here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs

Comment: How do we bind the tab content to a separate html file like we could do in uib-tabs. Could not find any details about it. Please share if you have any idea about this.